# How to make the block fill width of the parent (not only visible window)?

Tags: css

How can I make the block B fill the width like block A when I scroll horizontally?

html:

```
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#main div {
    display: inline-block; /*or block*/
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tombrito/hc9b8s06/1/

Comment: I dont understand, you want the block b to cross with the scrollbar this is it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because block A overflows the parent, and block B is only as wide as the parent.

Instead, you should make the parent expand in order to contain block A. You can achieve this with

```css
#main {
  display: inline-block; /* (at least) as wide as contents */
  min-width: 100%; /* but grow to fill available space, if any */
}
```

```css
#main {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 100%;
}
#main div {
  display: inline-block; /*or block*/
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">B</div>
</div>
```

Comment: f*** didn't remember the parent. ;)